# Populating a string array in Python - beginner CS homework question

Tags: python, list

Spent a long time struggling with this relatively simple question about populating a tic tac toe board.

```
# List variable ticTacToe should eventually 
# hold [ [ a, b, c ], [ d, e, f ], [ g, h, i ]]
# to represent the Tic Tac to board:
#    a b c
#    d e f
#    g h i
```

`ticTacToe = [ [], [], [] ]`

```
firstRow = input()

secondRow = input()

thirdRow = input()

ticTacToe.append(firstRow)

ticTacToe.append(secondRow)

ticTacToe.append(thirdRow)    

#Output handled for you
```

`for i in range(3) :
  for j in range(3) :
    print( "%3s" % ticTacToe[i][j], end="")
  print()`

The output was given to me and can't be replaced.

I'm having two problems here.

1. I can't get the row inside the [] without deleting the brackets and starting over. If I were to print ticTacToe I'd get `[[], [], [], 'a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i']` instead of `[[a,b,c], [d,e,f], [g,h,i]]`
2. Unwanted quotation marks keep appearing. If `first row = a,b,c` , when I append it into ticTacToe it shows up as `['a,b,c']` instead of `[a,b,c]`

Not sure where I'm going wrong and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you are confusing variable names, strings that hold `'a,b,c'` with list of strings that hold `['a','b','c']` - from your code it is unclear if you stuff variables inside a list or the strings holding 1 letter each ...

Comment: The list initially had `[ [], [], [] ]` and you are appending to that. So there is no surprise in what you got. Remember `.append()` just adds entry at the end of list.

Comment: The parts I wrote myself are the inputs and the appending. The input comes in as a string.

Answer (score 2):

You should read about lists: [PyTut lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
board = [ [], [], [] ]       # a list of 3 other lists

# addd somthing to board:    
board.append("something")    # now its a list of 3 lists and 1 string
print(board)

board = board + ["otherthing"]   # now its a list of 3 lists and 2 strings
print(board)


# modify the list inside board on place 0:
zero_innerlist = board[0]        # get the list at pos 0 of board
print(board)          
zero_innerlist.append("cat")     # put something into that inner list
print(board)
zero_innerlist.append("dog")     # put more into that inner list
print(board)
print(zero_innerlist)            # print "just" the inner list

one_innerlist = board[1]         # modify the 2nd inner list at pos 1
one_innerlist.append("demo")
print(board)
```

Outputs:

```
[[], [], [], 'something', 'otherthing']                     # board
[[], [], [], 'something', 'otherthing']                     # board
[['cat'], [], [], 'something', 'otherthing']                # board
[['cat', 'dog'], [], [], 'something', 'otherthing']         # board
['cat', 'dog']                                              # zero_innerlist
[['cat', 'dog'], ['demo'], [], 'something', 'otherthing']   # board
```

If you want to add 3 things to each of the inner lists, you need 3 appends to each of the inner lists.

---

Other nice read: [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#string-formatting) and [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

You are using the 2.7 style printing, for 3 and 3.6 format and f-strings are better:

```
board = [ ["a","b","c"], ["d","e","f"], ["g","h","i"] ]

for i in range(3) :
    for j in range(3) :
        print( f"{board[i][j]:3s}", end="")
    print()

# or 

for row in board:
    for col in row:
        print( f"{col:3s}", end="")
    print()

# or 

for row in board:
    print( f"{row[0]:3s}{row[1]:3s}{row[2]:3s}")

# or 

print( '\n'.join( ( ''.join(f"{col:3s}" for col in row ) for row in board) ))
```

Output (all):

```
a  b  c  
d  e  f  
g  h  i
```

Comment: That's a very detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple loop through input splitted on space and append to `ticTacToe` list:

```
ticTacToe = []
for x in input('Enter rows (each element separated by comma) separated by space: ').split():
    ticTacToe.append(x.split(','))

print(ticTacToe)
#Output handled for you
```

**Sample run**:

```
Enter rows (each element separated by comma) separated by space: a,b,c d,e,f g,h,i
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

---

Or, the whole thing in one line:

```
ticTacToe = [x.split(',') for x in input('Enter rows (each element separated by comma) separated by space: ').split()]
```

Comment: Glad, you solved it. If my or any other answer here helped, please press tick on left of answer, so it would be help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in python the quotation marks indicate a string, so you must have them there.

Since `ticTacToe` is a list of lists, you're appending your inputs to the outermost list. To append to the inner lists:

```
ticTacToe = [ [], [], [] ]

firstRow = input()
secondRow = input()
thirdRow = input()

ticTacToe[0].append(firstRow)
ticTacToe[1].append(secondRow)
ticTacToe[2].append(thirdRow)  

# ticTacToe >>> [['a,b,c'], ['d,e,f'], ['g,h,i']]
```

However, going off of the output code, it would seem that this is not what your instructor wants you to do.

Instead, each of the lists need to contain a single character and not the entire string of characters.

It would look something like this:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

There are many ways to do this, but here is one:

```
ticTacToe = [[], [], []]

firstRow = input()
secondRow = input()
thirdRow = input()

ticTacToe[0] = firstRow.split(",")
ticTacToe[1] = secondRow.split(",")
ticTacToe[2] = thirdRow.split(",")
```

The `split` method takes a string and converts it into a list provided a delimiter, a '`,`' in this case. It then assigns (not appends) to the inner lists. (Note: this won't work if you put a space after your commas, but I'll let you figure that one out)